# How to create chat application in android?

Tags: android, chat

I have to create a chat module in my android app. I created the layout for that and used a 9 patch image for displaying messages. Now I want to know how the messages are displayed in the left and right areas of the screen.

This is my screen

> [image]

Comment: Currently, your question is pretty broad.  What have you tried so far? What were the results of your attempts?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android

This is XMPP based chat application source code.
this is a very nice opensource chat Application. have a look at this code.You will surely get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom `Listview` and display your messages on right and other messages on left vice versa...for this you need to create custom XML and give left align and right align for the views(Messages).

Answer (score 1):

For this inside your Adapter class in data structure you passed to adapter maintain the variable for message whether its own message(Right side) or others mesage (Left side) and now **inside your getview() method you can set the gravity of that window or textview LEFT or RIGHT**

Use **textview.setLayoutGravity  left/right**

HOpe this helps